# Settings bounds on a hash algorithm

Tags: c++, hash

Is it sufficient to add a `% tableSize;` to the end of a hash function to ensure you use all of the available memory but do not exceed it?

EG:

I'm using the following function from the GeneralHashFunctions library

```
unsigned int DJBHash(const std::string& str)
{
   unsigned int hash = 5381;

   for(std::size_t i = 0; i < str.length(); i++)
   {
      hash = ((hash << 5) + hash) + str[i];
   }

   return hash;
}
```

This is how it appears in my program:

```
unsigned int Hash::hash(string key)
{
   unsigned int hash = 5381;

   for(size_t i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
      hash = (((hash << 5) + hash) + key[i]);
   }

   return hash % tableSize;
}
```

Will this do what I need it to do, or is there other alterations I need to make?

Comment: The modulo operation should be done after you calculate the hash, not during. The function does not actually return the hash of the given string, the name of your function lies.

Comment: Fixed, thanks. I'm not sure why I didn't see that. I guess I've just been working on this for so long I've started reading what I know the code "should" do and not actually what it does. 

Time to break out the whiteboard and start tracing stuff.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

It's indeed sufficient. As noted, it should be done *after* your hash function, but that's a detail. (You want to reuse the same hash function for different table sizes).

The worst thing that can happen is that your hash function returns a value not a lot larger than `tableSize`. For instance, if the max value is `tableSize+1`, then the first bucket will be twice as likely. If the max value is `tableSize*2 - 1`, the last bucket is half as likely. That's only a performance issue. Also, it's unlikely to hurt this specific case - on systems where `unsigned int` is 16 bits, you'll always have performance problems with 32000+ strings in your hashtable.